# How to create column that indicates number of times that an ID appear?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm looking to create a column that indicates, for every unique value, the number of times that it appears in a data set.  I would like to generate the frequency column in the data frame below:

```
ID     Frequency
111       4
205       2
603       6
111       4
```

In the original data, `111` appeared 4 times, `205` appeared 2 times, and `603` appeared 6 times, etc.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(N=n())` loading `dplyr` first!

Comment: @duck great solution. would it be possible to do this without eliminating the other columns in the data frame?

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(N=n())`

Comment: @Duck that worked, thank you so much!

Comment: If you feel comfortable, I can add as answer, and you could potentially accept as I was the first on posting the approach. Do you agree?

Comment: Certainly. That's totally fair.

Comment: Done, many thanks for be a fair user.

Comment: Also rewarded for being a fair user!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on **@rogues77** comments, and after having given the approach initially, the solution can be:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code 1
newdf <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(N=n())
#Code 2
newdf <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(N=n())
```

Answer (score 2):

With the input data `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, use `ave` with `length`.  No packages are used.

```
nr <- nrow(DF)
transform(DF, Freq = ave(1:nr, ID, FUN = length))
```

giving:

```
   ID Freq
1 111    2
2 205    1
3 603    1
4 111    2
```

or with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Freq = n()) %>%
  ungroup
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "ID
111       
205       
603       
111       "
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, Freq := .N, ID]
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c(111L, 205L, 603L, 111L)), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```